# What's the name for this kind of writing?

Tags: writing, books

I recently 'fell in love' with reading after receiving a book.

Now that I've finished reading it, I'm looking for books with that kind of writing. I've Googled for similar books from the same author, but reviews suggest that they're not as good.

Anyway, now here's my real question:

What is this kind of writing (or style?) called? I just love how they express (is that the correct word?) themselves or maybe it's because it's a little 'deep'. It's just so hard to describe!

[Taken from book]

> He swept the floor and lay down, using the book he had just finished reading as a pillow. He told himself that he would have to start reading thicker books: they lasted longer, and made more comfortable pillows.
>
> He aroused... He had noticed that, as soon as he awoke, most of his animals also begin to stir. "They are so used to me that they know my schedule", he muttered. Thinking for a moment, he realised that it could be the other way round: that it was he who had become accustomed to their schedule.

What exactly is the name for this kind of writing?

Edit:I guess the correct term is the self conversations right?

Comment: We can't answer the question in the later edit, obviously. But are you asking for a name for the literary device of having a central character "talk to himself", as opposed to simply ***think*** things?

Comment: Jason  dude - could you simply **state the name of the book and the author** ???

Answer (score 2):

The genre might be called *stream of consciousness*, where the character has a dialogue with himself rather than with a second person.

A famous example of *stream of consciousness* is James Joyce's "Ulysses", circa 1920. This style is also common in traditions of oral storytelling, such as American Indian sagas.

Answer (score 0):

It is prose. And simple prose at that. That is the writing style. Along the spectrum of prose Ernest Hemingway is a lot closer to *[The Alchemist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alchemist_%28novel%29)* than James Joyce. The genre is an allegory or fable. I haven't this book, so I guess my life hasn't been "changed forever" (blurb about the book), but apparently the story told in the book had already been written in earlier books. You might like *The Little Prince* by Antoine de Saint-Exupery, if you haven't read that. Or *Jonathan Livingston Seagull* by Richard Bach, or *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance* by Robert Pirsig.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a *[Bildungsroman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bildungsroman)*. Novels in this genre tend to help people realize there is pleasure in reading, especially young people.

I will copy a passage from *Ulysses* (not a Bildungsroman) taken at random if you want to compare:

> He crossed at Nassau street corner and stood before the window of
>   Yeates and Son, pricing the field glasses. Or will I drop into old
>   Harris's and have a chat with young Sinclair? Wellmannered fellow.
>   Probably at his lunch. Must get those old glasses of mine set right.
>   Goerz lenses, six guineas. Germans making their way everywhere. Sell
>   on easy terms to capture trade. Undercutting. Might chance on a pair
>   in the railway lost property office. Astonishing the things people
>   leave behind them in trains and cloak rooms. What do they be thinking
>   about? Women too. Incredible. Last year travelling to Ennis had to
>   pick up that farmer's daughter's bag and hand it to her at Limerick
>   junction. Unclaimed money too. There's a little watch up there on the
>   roof of the bank to test those glasses by.